# How to rename a table column in Oracle 10g

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I would like to know:
How to rename a table column in Oracle 10g?

Answer (score 123, accepted):

```
SQL> create table a(id number);

Table created.

SQL> alter table a rename column id to new_id;

Table altered.

SQL> desc a
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- -----------
 NEW_ID                                             NUMBER
```

Comment: had to use `COLUMN` keyword before the column name.

Answer (score 38):

The syntax of the query is as follows:

```
Alter table <table name> rename column <column name> to <new column name>;
```

Example:

```
Alter table employee rename column eName to empName;
```

To rename a column name without space to a column name with space:

```
Alter table employee rename column empName to "Emp Name";
```

To rename a column with space to a column name without space:

```
Alter table employee rename column "emp name" to empName;
```

Answer (score 21):

```
alter table table_name rename column oldColumn to newColumn;
```

Answer (score 3):

suppose supply_master is a table, and

```
SQL>desc supply_master;


SQL>Name
 SUPPLIER_NO    
 SUPPLIER_NAME
 ADDRESS1       
 ADDRESS2       
 CITY           
 STATE          
 PINCODE  


SQL>alter table Supply_master rename column ADDRESS1 TO ADDR;
Table altered



SQL> desc Supply_master;
 Name                   
 -----------------------
 SUPPLIER_NO            
 SUPPLIER_NAME          
 ADDR   ///////////this has been renamed........//////////////                
 ADDRESS2               
 CITY                   
 STATE                  
 PINCODE
```

Answer (score 1):

```
alter table table_name 
rename column old_column_name/field_name to new_column_name/field_name;
```

example: `alter table student rename column name to username;`