# convert oracle table column name to MM/DD/YYYY

Tags: oracle, date

I would like convert the column name to date.
for example the **column name** is today, i want to convert it dynamically to today's date like MM/DD/YYYY .

Comment: What date do you want to use if the column name is not "today"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to rename a table column in Oracle 10g](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13878383/how-to-rename-a-table-column-in-oracle-10g)

Comment: My question is: why?

Comment: @MichaelMcGriff I want to use the current date as the column name..
example: as of now the column name is "Today" i want it to be current date "12/12/2014".

Comment: I get that, I just thought you wanted to be more dynamic about it going forward.  The link I put above should get you all you need to know then.

Answer (score 2):

> as of now the column name is "Today" i want it to be current date

You can't configure a column to change its name automagically. To reflect the current day or whatever else.

*But*, you can change the column name by using an alias when doing a query. In order to make the things the more transparent as possible, you might want to create a view. Here is an example:

```
-- Some table with a column  named "TODAY"
CREATE TABLE T AS (SELECT LEVEL today FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL < 5);


-- Use PL/SQL to create a view on the given table
-- with a dynamic column name
DECLARE
  today varchar(10) := TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DD/MM/YYYY');
  query varchar(200) := 'CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW V'
                     || ' AS SELECT today "' || today || '"'
                     || ' FROM T';
BEGIN
  execute immediate query;
END;
```

Then, to query the "table" with the *right* column name, you will simply need to query `V` instead of `T`:

```
SELECT * FROM V;

12/12/2014
1
2
3
4
```

If you recreate your view daily, say by calling the above PL/SQL code from a [job](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_sched.htm#i1000363), you will see each day a view with the current date as the column name. But, as the underlying table is left unchanged, you will still be able to query it using the canonical name `today`. Which is important for example if you need to perform join on that table.

---

*That being said, I'm not sure I will push toward such a solution. Use at your own risks!*

Answer (score 1):

If you want the column name heading to appear as something different than what the column name is defined in the table, you simply use the `as "DisplayColumnName"` clause for that column:

```sql
select user_name, today as "12/12/2014" from some_table;
```

But you would need to programatically generate the SQL statement for that to work. What coding environment you are using would dictate how to dynamically create a select statement.